# Does an off-the-shelf server with Windows Server 2008 on it, include the VC90 CRT?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, msvcrt

Same question for Windows Server 2003.

Do I need to direct people to install the [VC 2008 sp1 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2)?

Is the answer dependent upon whether the Server runs an x64 or x86 build?

Does the VC Runtime get pushed out with Microsoft Update, or Windows Update?

Comment: Do you mean, "Windows Server 2008 / 2003"?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm asking about. The server OS.  I modified the title and text to use the full name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't get distributed with Windows, you'll have to deploy it yourself.  Yes, Microsoft will update it when it contains a critical security flaw.  Like the one you linked to.  You'll want [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=294DE390-3C94-49FB-A014-9A38580E64CB&displaylang=en).  You'll need the x64 version if you built your program with the x64 compiler.

Hmm, reminds me of another thread...

Comment: You're not missing anything, it was about log4net.